# CKEDITOR selection.getStartElement() give wrong element in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, ckeditor

I have a main page which has ckeditor to perform some text editing.
ckeditor contains below elements:

```
<address>Address<address><pincode>123456</pincode>
```

I try to get focused element as

```
 editorinstance1.focus();

var temp =editorinstance1.getSelection().getStartElement();
```

or

```
var temp =editorinstance1.document.getSelection().getStartElement();
```

when I click before the pincode element's first char

actually I need cursor position like

`<pincode>[cursor here]123456</pincode>`

the code working fine except chrome

chrome return address element.

how do I get correct element.
Just I checked with HTML it also same problem.(http://jsfiddle.net/z5ABt/2/)

I also reported in [code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337757](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337757)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug in chrome

you may use only like below.

```
<panel  contenteditable="true">
    <div id="address" contenteditable="true">Address</div>
    <span contenteditable="true">, </span>
    <span contenteditable="false"></span>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="pin">123456</div>
</panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Chrome, when you click on the first character it focuses the wrong edit area. When you don't use nested `contenteditable`, it seems to work fine.

```
<panel>
    <div id="address" contenteditable="true">Address</div>
    <span contenteditable="true">, </span>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="pin">123456</div>
</panel>
```

Clicking on the `1` will focus the correct edit area.

I can't find a ticket in their bug tracker about this specific issue, but they do have a number of issues regarding nested `contenteditable`. You might want to make a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: i should use nested contenteditable.bug report posting link please